# how to download jar dependencies while installing jar into m2 repo

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I have a maven plugin jar which is already built on another machine , say test-1.0.0.jar . This jar have multiple dependencies like apache,plexus,maven etc .
e.g.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.9</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-archiver</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-common</artifactId>
      <version>2.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
      <artifactId>surefire-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-component-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
       <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
       <version>2.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Now I want to use this jar for my maven project so I installed it in my local repository. when I install it using 'mvn install:install-file' command , it does not download all required dependencies for the jar in m2 repository. So when I use this plugin in my new maven project , it gives me classNotFound exception.

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: com.test.status.test.MyTestCompileMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/util/scan/InclusionScanException
```

My projects POM -

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.check.status</groupId>
  <artifactId>cf</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.test.status</groupId>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies/>
</project>
```

Comment: Can't you just run `mvn clean install` to install it?

Comment: no.. i dont have code base.. I just have already installed jar (using mvn clean install) and I need to install it in my local repo

Comment: But this is what `mvn install` exactly does...

Comment: I am installing jar file in local repo using -'mvn install:install-file -Dfile=test-1.0.0.jar -DgroupId=com.test.status -DartifactId=test -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=maven-plugin' command .. It downloads some dependencies but not all ..

Comment: Please give more info about `classNotFound` exception.

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 1):

You should add your `test-1.0.0.jar` dependency into your pom.xml `<dependencies>`.

And executing maven with `-U` parameter should force a check for missing releases and updated snapshots on remote repositories. For example:

```
mvn -U clean install
```

Actually executing the goal `dependency:resolve` will only download dependencies without doing anything else.

```
mvn dependency:resolve
```

Comment: no.. I dont have a code base. I have a jar file which I will install in my local repo using - 'mvn install:install-file -Dfile=test-1.0.0.jar -DgroupId=com.test.status -DartifactId=test -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=maven-plugin'

Comment: Why `test-1.0.0.jar` isn't in your `pom.xml` ?

Comment: it is there.. added in plugins section

Comment: Add it into also your `<dependencies> `

Comment: But I want to use it as a plugin to my project

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dependencies from test-1.0.0.jar into your maven project.

```
(pom.xml) test-1.0.0.jar  ---copy dependencies---> new maven project
```

Comment: It will work like that .. But I dont want to add dependencies in my project.

Comment: @Disha Why you don't want add this dependency.